# Facebook Login Integration

Tags: iphone, facebook-login

I have an app proj and facebook sample login proj. I need to combine both together so user are prompt to login with facebook then lead to the app. I have no idea how to start and if my method is correct.

What i did:
Just insert delegate.m, delegate.h, login.m, login.h, login.xib files as another class group in my app.
Copy the view in login.xib and paste it in the mainwindow.xib.
Custom the class as FBLoginView (given as an option).

the error i got:

> 2012-12-05 14:43:17.370 myapp[2312:c07] Unknown class FBLoginView in
>   Interface Builder file. 2012-12-05 14:43:17.400 myapp[2312:c07]
>   Unknown class FBLoginView in Interface Builder file. 2012-12-05
>   14:43:17.403 myapp[2312:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
>   exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[
>   setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value
>   coding-compliant for the key delegate.'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x19ce012 0x2181e7e 0x1a56fb1 0x652711 0x5d3ec8 0x5d39b7 0x9d2573 0x5fe428 0xb9f0cc 0x2195663 0x19c945a
>   0xb9dbcf 0xb9f98d 0x981ceb 0x982002 0x980ed6 0x992315 0x99324b
>   0x984cf8 0x281edf9 0x281ead0 0x1943bf5 0x1943962 0x1974bb6 0x1973f44
>   0x1973e1b 0x9807da 0x98265c 0x2c8d 0x2bc5) libc++abi.dylib: terminate
>   called throwing an exception (lldb)

Is there anyway to fix this, or should there be a better way of integration?

Please help thanks.

Comment: Which project did u try and integrate ??

Comment: my own proj. and facebook sessionlogin

Comment: just started coding for school purpose. xcode amatuer..

Comment: Hello there facing same problem i added -ObjC in otherlinkflags thats solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem yesterday. There are two solutions for this:

1. Go to Target Settings -> Build Settings, in the `Other Linker Flags` write `-ObjC`
2. In the App Delegate, update didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function and add `[FBLoginView class]`, for example:

---

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary     *)launchOptions
{
    [FBLoginView class];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

REFERENCE: https://developers.facebook.com/ios/login-ui-control/

UPDATE by @shashwat:

Adding flag is [not a best option always](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-tutorial)

> you may want to also add the -ObjC linker flag to your project.
>   However, if you choose to do this you will be increasing the size of
>   your executable (due to additional SDK object code loaded into your
>   application). You can learn more about this trade off, what exactly
>   the -ObjC flag does, and how to set it in our troubleshooting guide.

Adding `[FBLoginView class];` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am providing a simple project for posting on facebook. Please check this out. Also u need an API key from facebook , either get it from the sample code you are using like the one I provided to you below but it would really just show whats in the project. Or get your own key  from the Facebook Developers account, get it made then use it in the project.

http://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API

Comment: Thanks. but i dont get how it can integrate with my own project as it is a separate file. Im acquiring on how i can combine facebook login with an already started proj. do you happen to know about this?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem, and this document is valuable for solving problem.
(Please see "Graphically" section in this page)

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/login-ui-control/

It may also be helpful for you.